# Nested Loop for Rows and Column

Tags: java, html, jsp

How to utilize nested for loop in this scenario in order to display 25 records directly without manually increased the counter i ? As I want to display 5 columns of movie details in one row, then another 5 columns of movie details in next row? Thank You, Your help is much appreciated.

```
<% for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++){ %>
                <img src="<%= movieList.get(i).getMoviePoster() %>">
                <p ><%= movieList.get(i).getMovieName() %></p>
                <button onclick="location.href='booknow.html#movie1-showtimes'" target="_self" type="button" class="btn">Book Now</button>
            </div>
            <div style="margin: -409px 0 40px 200px;">
                <img src="<%= movieList.get(i+1).getMoviePoster() %>">
                <p><%= movieList.get(i+1).getMovieName() %></p>
                <button onclick="location.href='booknow.html#movie2-showtimes'" target="_self" type="button" class="btn">Book Now</button>
            </div>
            <div style="margin: -419px 0 30px 397px;">
                <img src="<%= movieList.get(i+2).getMoviePoster() %>">
                <p><%= movieList.get(i+2).getMovieName() %></p>
                <button onclick="location.href='booknow.html#movie3-showtimes'" target="_self" type="button" class="btn">Book Now</button>
            </div>
            <div style="margin: -408px 0 30px 593px;">
                <img src="<%= movieList.get(i+3).getMoviePoster() %>" >
                <p><%= movieList.get(i+3).getMovieName() %></p>
                <button onclick="location.href='booknow.html#movie4-showtimes'" target="_self" type="button" class="btn">Book Now</button>
            </div>
            <div style="margin: -410px 0 30px 789px;">
                <img src="<%= movieList.get(i+4).getMoviePoster() %>" >
                <p><%= movieList.get(i+4).getMovieName() %></p>
                <button onclick="location.href='booknow.html#movie5-showtimes'" target="_self" type="button" class="btn">Book Now</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% } %>
```

Comment: Is your HTML even correct?

Comment: I would assume you could use normal java syntax and use for(int i = 0; i < movieList.size(); i++)